# Почему я не могу выбрать основной домен в Google Search Console?

Tags: seo, домен, google-search-console

Захожу в "Настройки сайта" в Google Search Console. Выбираю основной домен (site.com - без www) и нажимаю на "Сохранить".

В ответ получаю сообщение:

> Процедура назначения основного домена предполагает проверку вашего
>   права собственности на домен http://www.site.com/. Подтвердите
>   право собственности на домен http://www.site.com/.

Я не понимаю как и где мне его подтвердить? В документации не нашел ничего по этому поводу.

Answer (score 2):

1. **[Добавьте ваш сайт](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592)** или нажмите *Управление ресурсом > Подтвердить право на ресурс* рядом с существующим ресурсом на главной странице **[Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home)**.
2. Также вы можете использовать указанные **[здесь методы подтверждения](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=ru#verification_details)**.

Справка Гул **[Как подтвердить право собственности на сайт](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35179?hl=ru)**.

Comment: Я не настолько тупой, чтобы не заметить элементарных кнопок. Права на ресурс подтверждены. В гугле почти 100,000 страниц.